MERN Stack Blog Integration Error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' is not valid JSON" in Console
I have a personal portfolio website, I am integrating a blog in my portfolio, I have made using MERN stack, i am getting the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON" in console
Following is the link to the git repository of the project
Priyanshu Portfolio - GitHub 
Following is the code block you may refer to for a quick view
Fetching in frontend
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBlogs = async () => {
      try {
        const url = `${host}/blog/blogs`;
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "authtoken": localStorage.getItem("token")
          },
        });
        const allblogs = await response.json();
        setBlogs(allblogs);
        setLoading(false);
        extractUniqueTags(allblogs);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching blogs:', error.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchBlogs();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

Sending from backend
router.get('/blogs', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const blogPosts = await BlogPost.find();
        res.json({blogPosts: blogPosts});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send("Some Error occurred");
    }
});


I guess the request never reaches this middleware, maybe the HTML code is sent from a 404 handler or an earlier middleware.

Looks like your response is coming in as HTML, not JSON.  This can happen if the request failed for some reason (say, getting a 404 instead of your JSON).  Try to just console.log() the response once the promise fulfills and see what the response actually is.
